# Why i get the same MSE value for two least square models that differ in one explanatory variable?

Tags: least-squares, prediction, bias, mse, bias-variance-tradeoff

I have two ols-regression models that just differ in one variable. It means that one model have the same variables like the other plus an explanatory variable more. I estimated both models on a train set and want compare the prediction of both models on a test set by computing the mse. As a result i get for both models the same mse. I dont understand the result because i thought if a have more flexible model what mean i add a variable the bias goes down and the variance rise up. If the bias shrinks more than the variance go up i get a smaller mse and vice versa. 
So i thought the mse values of the two models should different, depending on how the variance bias trade-off will be in the modell with the extra explanatory variable .

So my question is why I get the same mse value if i have a different number of explanatory variables?

Comment: If the variable you added is insignificant and its estimate is close to zero, it will have negligible effect on the MSE (since the model without it effectively just has its parameter set at 0)

Comment: @Xiaomi From where do you have this information, maybe you can link a paper or a book. I read that the significance of a variable doesn't automatically mean that it is a good variable for prediction.